# Stopping form from submitting until all dropdown boxes are completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have created an HTML form that is generated from a PHP script. The PHP script outputs an HTML dropdown based on data held in a database. The number of dropdowns being displayed on the page varies as it is based on the number of lines in a MySQL database. All the dropdowns have the same ID `inputDropdown`

I am trying to create a jquery script that prevents the form from being submitted until all the dropdown boxes have been completed (So whenever the value doesn't equal `No Response`).

This is the HTML code outputted from the PHP Script. Please note the number in the name (E.G. "1" in `dropdown_1`) is generated based on the ID of a row in the database.

```
<select name="dropdown_1" id="inputDropdown" class="form-control">
        <option value="No Response" selected>Blank - Please Select A Option</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
        <option value="Full">Yes</option>
</select>
<select name="dropdown_2" id="inputDropdown" class="form-control">
        <option value="No Response" selected>Blank - Please Select A Option</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
        <option value="Full">Yes</option>
</select>
<select name="dropdown_3" id="inputDropdown" class="form-control">
        <option value="No Response" selected>Blank - Please Select A Option</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
        <option value="Full">Yes</option>
</select>
```

I tried the following jquery Code, however, this only worked for the first of the dropdowns and didn't check the other dropdown values.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#update-form").submit(function (e) {
        if ($('#inputDropdown').val() == 'No Response') {
            alert('Please complete all the boxes');
        }
        e.preventDefault(e);
    });
    $("#inputDropdown").change(function () {
        $("#inputDropdown").submit();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Please, could someone advise of an efficient way on how to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Replace your `inputDropdown` ids with classes. You can only have a given ID on a single element so the function is only applying to one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first issue is that you have repeated the same `id` in the DOM, which is invalid. Use a `class` to group the elements instead.

Then you can use `filter()` to find how many of the selects still have the first option selected when the form is submit. If any of them do, show the `alert()`. You also need to call `preventDefault()` at this point only. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#update-form").submit(function(e) {
    var unselected = $('.inputDropdown').filter(function() {
      return $(this).find('option:selected').index() == 0;
    }).length;
  
    if (unselected != 0) {
      e.preventDefault(e);
      alert('Please complete all the boxes');
    }
  });
  
  $(".inputDropdown").change(function() {
    $("#update-form").submit();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="update-form" action="#">
<select name="dropdown_1" class="form-control inputDropdown">
  <option value="No Response" selected>Blank - Please Select A Option</option>
  <option value="No">No</option>
  <option value="Full">Yes</option>
</select>
<select name="dropdown_2" class="form-control inputDropdown">
  <option value="No Response" selected>Blank - Please Select A Option</option>
  <option value="No">No</option>
  <option value="Full">Yes</option>
</select>
<select name="dropdown_3" class="form-control inputDropdown">
  <option value="No Response" selected>Blank - Please Select A Option</option>
  <option value="No">No</option>
  <option value="Full">Yes</option>
</select>
</form>
```